# How do you escape "}" using roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm documenting a function using `roxygen2` with an `@example`.

The example has a string that contains a `}` symbol.

```
#' ...
#' @examples
#' \dontrun{
#' ## polyline joining the capital cities of Australian states
#' pl <- "nnseFmpzsZgalNytrXetrG}krKsaif@kivIccvzAvvqfClp~uBlymzA~ocQ}_}iCthxo@srst@"
#'
#' df_polyline <- decodepl(pl)
#' }
#' ...
```

When built, the documentation for the example is

[image]

Where everything after the first `}` is cutt off.

How do I escape the `}` so that it is included in the string in the example?

I've tried a backslash `\{` / `\\{` with no luck.

---

### Update - 01 Sep 2016

The [official response](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/476#issuecomment-243814895) to my issue from Hadley

> Fixing this is quite difficult (as far as I can it will require writing a considerably more complicated Rd parser), and it's a rare occurrence, so realistically this is never going to get high up enough on my to do list to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLDR: longer term fix: file [an issue](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues).

You "got lucky" this built since you had just enough `}`'s to get past some Rd installation errors.

I even tried using `@example inst/examples/ex.r` and putting the code (with the `\dontrun{}` wrapper since it is supported there) and the same thing happens with that method since the same roxygen parsing/translating code seems to be in play there too.

- SHORT TERM FIX #1: manually edit the generated `Rd` file to do the single `\}` for each of the `}`. To make this something you don't accidentally overwrite, generate it once, do the fix then de-roxygenize that function until there's a fix.
- SHORT TERM FIX #2: for that bit of code, the string assignment can happen outside of the `\dontrun{}` block (which is really what's causing this). Move it out and you can continue with roxygenizing.
- LONG TERM FIX: file an issue to the above URL.

Comment: Maybe #3: Replace `}` in the string by `\u007d`. Haven't tried it, but will probably work.

Comment: I've expanded on #2 and removed `\dontrun{ }`. The example can happily be run :)

Comment: @lukeA - yes, that appears to work too, thanks. However, I'd like to keep the string 'as-is', so I've also filed an issue.

Comment: I've updated my question with a response from Hadley - this issue is unlikely to get fixed.